# Sum price of one to many relation ship (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have problem with one to many relation ship! So im try to sum product prices so here is what i mean:

**Model:**
Product.php

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

**Model:**
Orders.php

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

So i want make smth like this: $var->product->price->sum();

My database if it needed:

Orders:

     `id product_id|user_id|
     |-|----------|-------|
     |1|1         |1      |
     | |          |       |`

And Products have only 4 columns: `id,name,price,description`

I mean that:

```
 products:

  id\1

  name\productname

  price \1.00USD

  id\2

  name\productname2

  price \1.00USD
```

It must return sum of all product so it must return 2.00USD

@Jonas Staudenmeir

Comment: You have only one item per order? If not then you may need `many to many` relation with intermediate table. [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Yes i have only one item per order

Comment: What exactly do you want to sum? What's `$var`?

Comment: If you have only one product then why use `sum`?  You may try `$order->product->price;`. If you have `quantity` field in the order you may multiply the price with that.

Comment: hmm.. Can u explain me how it will be done with many to many relation ships?

Comment: Is `$var` a single order here?

Comment: @apokryfos i just give example with $var i want to make all donation price with orders of users i just want get all products by id and sum their prices

Comment: Do you mean something like `$user->priceSum`?

Comment: now i mean $total->priceSum

Comment: What's `$total`?

Comment: Listen guys, i want to make mounthly turnover only i need product_id and sum all of products prices do u understand what i want to make?

Comment: $total is just example what i want..

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: From your example, it looks like you want the sum of all the products. How is that related to the orders?

Comment: By id, Orders: `id,product_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eloquent models without `DB`

```
Product::with(['orders' => function($query){
   $query->sum('price');
}])->get();
```

Comment: the goal is not to get product, but orders whose product have those prices to be summed up

Answer (score 2):

try this QueryBuilder Query :

```
 DB::table('orders')
    ->leftJoin('products','orders.product_id','=','products.id')
    ->where('orders.user_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->select('orders.*','products.*',DB::raw("SUM(products.price) as order_total"))
    ->groupBy('orders.product_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution! So i make that

I use current relation ship like befor and i make that function in my
order.php **model**

```
public function getTotalPrice() {

$orders = self::with('product')->get();

$total = 0;

foreach($orders as $order) {
 $total += $order->product->price;
} 

return $total;
}
```

Now i can use my function like obj and call it `$var->getTotalPrice();`

Comment: A bit shorter: `$total = $orders->pluck('product')->sum('price');`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 6+ we can use like this, very straight forward

```
$total = $order->product->sum('price');
```